# Ticks length in FrameTicks not correct

Tags: plotting, labeling, ticks

I need ticks with equal lenghts to the outside (`plen`) and to the inside (`mlen`) of the frame of a plot. I have:

```
plen=0.0015;
mlen=0.0015;
xTicks = Table[{i, i, {plen, mlen}}, {i, 0, 4, 0.2}];
```

and I am using `Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}}, FrameTicks -> {xTicks, Automatic}`.

The problem is, the ticks in the resulting image, as seen after exporting to pdf and zoomed in, do not have the same lenght in both directions.

This works if I use `Ticks` instead, or if the value is changed to `0.003` or above, but I need to use a frame, as I don't know how to force the ticks labels out of the frame by using `Ticks`, and I need them to be less than 0.003, as I want to distinguish them from other ticks (placed elsewhere) which are about the same lenght.

**EDIT**: Example code:

```
Export["amazingplot.pdf", 
 Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 4}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {xTicks, Automatic}, ImageSize -> 1000]]
```

Comment: This seems OK in *Mathematica* 10.1 under Windows.  What version/platform are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I am using _Mathematica_ 12 under Windows 10. Meanwhile, I played around a bit and found out that using `Union[Table[{i, , {0, 0.0015}}, {i, 0, 4, 
  0.02}], Table[{i, , {0, -0.0015}}, {i, 0, 4, 0.02}]]` (essentially adding _out_ and _in_ ticks separately) seems to work.

Comment: In MMA 12.0 on Win10-64 I get shorter outward ticks when I use your lengths (which, by the way, is TINY). If I use longer ticks, e.g. `plen = mlen = 0.005`, then everything seems to work. So, at your size, I can reproduce the problem, but at a longer length it goes away. So it's some awful tricky corner case perhaps in the conversion to PDF. What about other formats (e.g. raster PNG vs. vector SVG)?

Comment: @MarcoB: I'll try. In the meanwhile, I found a workaround, so I'd say it is not a PDF issue. **EDIT**: Confirmed, it's not.

Comment: @xihiro What's the workaround? You might want to put it in a self-answer to this question for others in the future.

Comment: @MarcoB: It's in the answer to Mr.Wizard. I'll add it as answer if no one finds something simpler (or the reason this is not working correctly).

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, this seems to be a problem with (at least) version 12.0.
**EDIT**: version 12.1 has the same issue.

There's a workaround, by writing a table for the *inward* ticks and another for the *outward* ones, only using a negative length:

```
outxTicks = Table[{i, i, {0,  0.0015}}, {i, 0, 4, 0.02}];
inxTicks  = Table[{i, i, {0, -0.0015}}, {i, 0, 4, 0.02}];
xTicks = Union[outxTicks,inxTicks];
```